Trigger Plugin when change in specific dropdown in Dynamics 365
Is it possible to trigger a plugin when a dropdown value changes to a specific option? If this is feasible, how to implement it?
For instance, I would like to trigger the plugin when the status is set to 'Contract Executed':

What are the steps that I need to follow to call plugin when a specific dropdown value is set?

Do you want to fire the action if the value is changed on the form or when the change is saved? Have you already consulted any tutorials like Tutorial: Write and register a plug-in ?

Hi, I'm new to MS Dynamics and still exploring different approaches to meet my requirement.
That's right, I want to trigger the plugin when the value is 'changed' in dropdown. There are API calls which I'll put in that plugin.
Thank's for the Tutorial link, I'm going throught that now... :)

In case you want to react to the form UI, you will need a Custom Action you can call from your UI form script.

This depends on what your plugin is doing. If your plugin will execute every time the dropdown value was change I hope that it's not creating a record.
There are 2 ways (I think) that can solve your problem:

Using only a plugin you can register your step on Create / Edit (if you use edit, include your dropdown as filtering attribute), from your logic you can check the value of your dropdown. But this will only execute when your record was saved.
Create a Dynamics Custom Api  (logic will be the same as your plugin) then you can trigger it onChange of your dropdown. Create and use custom APIs

